# Does anyone know of any low-poly 3D art tutorials?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

I've always been fascinated with low poly art styles. Throughout many years I tried to teach myself pixel art, but when low poly art was introduced to me during a time when I was looking for inspiration on a new project it was just fascinating. Here is an example of what I'd like to attempt:

[[Example 1] - A low poly 3D computer](https://dribbble.com/shots/989264-Computer?list=searches&tag=low_poly&offset=24)

Does anyone have any good resources or tutorials I can follow? The tools I have at my disposal include:

- Access to University Photoshop through virtual desktop
- Pixelmator

  I am looking for tutorials centered on 3D low-poly art that can be exported in order to view on the web as a 2D image. Here is another example from Google's Cubeslam game. I'm not quite sure what process their team approaches to make the art, [but here is the link to their FAQ page which features what I'm aiming for.](https://www.cubeslam.com/tech)

Comment: Please see the link above your question. There are several answers there which should help you.

Comment: @scott hes asking 3D, not 2d. Anyway you make them manually

Comment: @Joojaa Asking for Photoshop and Pixelmator, isn't 3d. The images linked to are *not* 3d images. Just because an artist uses shadows, perspective, and foreshortening in their art, it doesn't make them "3D" images.

Comment: @scott maybe, but the last sentence in the post seems to refute this?

Comment: Pixelmator and Photoshop are tools at my disposal, not necessarily what I will be using if a tutorial is using a different tool.

Comment: @scott I am not looking for tutorials on how to triangulate a portrait that is given to me. I want to make each and every component. I'm not quite sure how the process works, but I have taken 2D images and triangulated them, I just would like to create the image rather than triangulate what had already been made. If what I said does not make sense, I would like to know how those artists in the links I gave made their art. I am looking for tutorials centered on 3D low-poly art that can be exported in order to view on the web as a 2D image.

Comment: @scott I edited my question. I guess my only concern is that I'm not sure what the process is like. Are all poly images made to look 3D or where they drawn in a 3D plain?

Comment: Hi @Somnibyte what you posted are merely 2D images that use perspective and shadow. Most if not all of the images you see like this are 2D images. 3D models are a different matter. The low-poly appearance can certainly be done with a 3D model, but absolutely not with Photoshop and Pixelmator. If you use a 3D app such as Maya, or Blender then the question would be a different matter entirely.

Comment: The google link could easily be done in a 2D app by an artist. However, there's no direct way to know what was used. They could also be created in a 3D modeling application.

Comment: @Scott I understand what you mean now. Thank you so much for the information. I will find a method that suits me best and try to find some tutorials. I'll also use the link you gave me.